# Progressions and ratio problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The ratio of arithmetic mean and geometric mean of two numbers is 5:4. If the difference between their geometric mean and harmonic mean is (-0.8) find the numbers.  I tried using ratio property but I could not.

Comment: AM > GM > HM, So take (GM) - (HM)=0.8 and follow David's Solution, you shall get two sets of numbers, out of which one set satisfies the conditions given in the problem

Comment: @Vikram please give the complete solution

Answer (score 1):

if the numbers are $x$ and $y$ then:
$$
A = \frac12 (x+y) \\
G = \sqrt{xy} \\
H = \frac{2xy}{x+y}
$$
and the data of your problem are:
$$
G-H = \frac45 = \frac{G}{A}
$$
i.e., on multiplying through by $\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{xy}}$
$$
(x+y) - 2\sqrt{xy} = 2
$$
the LHS is $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2$ which gives you $\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{y}+\sqrt{2}$
you may now find $\sqrt{y}$ by substitution in the equation $5G=4A$

Comment: diff of G and H is -0.8

Comment: i assumed that OP's question concerned real numbers, which is usual in a problem at this level of difficulty. if i am wrong in that assumption then  a corresponding adjustment must be made to the above argument, yes.

Comment: Cool, thanx David, I got it :) , your soln works

Comment: $ G-H $=$\frac (-4)(5) $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Call your numbers $a$ and $b$. What are their geometric mean (say $x=?$) and their arithmetic mean (say $y=?$) in terms of $a$ and $b$ ?

Now you know that $\frac{y}{x}=\frac{5}{4}$ and ....

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Two equations and two unknowns !

Answer (score 0):

I will continue from where David left,

$$\sqrt x=\sqrt y+\sqrt 2 \Rightarrow x=y+2\sqrt{2y}+2, $$ substitute this in $\hspace{10 pt}5 GM=4 AM\hspace{10 pt}$which is $\hspace{10 pt}5\sqrt{xy}=4\frac{x+y}{2}$

$$5(\sqrt y+\sqrt 2)\sqrt y=2 ( y+2\sqrt{2y}+2+y ) $$

upon simplification we get, $$y+\sqrt{2y}-4=0$$ substitute $\sqrt y=m$ to get, $$m^2+\sqrt 2 m-4=0$$ $$m=-\sqrt 2 \Rightarrow y=2 \Rightarrow x=8$$ OR $$m=-2\sqrt 2 \Rightarrow y=8 \Rightarrow x=18$$

Now check which pair of $(8,2)$ and $(18,8)$ satisfies conditions given in the problem, that is the answer.

Comment: Sir but  $ GM-HM=-0.8$

Comment: GM is always greater than HM, then how can (GM)-(HM) be a negative number?

Comment: The AM, GM and HM of (-8) and (-2) are respectively (-5), (+4 or -4) and (-3.2). Here AM <GM <HM

Comment: your problem confuses us by stating that "difference between GM and HM is -0.8", and if we write it as it is then it will be GM-HM=-0.8, which will be wrong (generally this type of problems are for real numbers), hence we write it as HM-GM=-0.8 which is same as GM-HM=0.8

Comment: (8,2) satisfies all the conditions:AM=(8+2)/2=5 and GM=sqrt(8*2)=4

Comment: In fact the solution is (-8) and (-2). But I do not know the strategy

Comment: pls check if my calculations are correct

Comment: Of course yes.  But you have considered GM-HM =0.8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16566/discussion-between-achari-s-ganesha-and-vikram).

Comment: @AchariSGanesha, try recalculating everything with $\sqrt x=\sqrt y+\sqrt{-2}$

Answer (score 0):

After David and Vikram's hints I found the solution $$G-H=\frac{-4}{5}=\frac{-G}{A}$$ $$\sqrt{xy}-\frac{2xy}{x+y}=\frac{-2\sqrt {xy}}{(x+y)}$$ $$(x+y)-2\sqrt {xy}={-2}$$ $$(\sqrt x-\sqrt y)^2=-2$$ $$\sqrt x-\sqrt y=\sqrt {-2}$$ $$\sqrt x=\sqrt y+\sqrt {-2}$$ $$x=y-2+2\sqrt {-2y}$$ Substituting in $5G=4A$, we get $$5(\sqrt y+\sqrt {-2})\sqrt y=\frac{4(y-2+2\sqrt {-2y}+y)}{2}$$ put$\sqrt{-y}=m$ $$m^2-\sqrt 2m-4=0$$ $$(m-2\sqrt 2)(m+\sqrt 2)=0$$
solving for $x$ and $y$, we get $x=-8$ $y=-2$